# Need to merge values in array

Tags: javascript, lodash, ecmascript-5

I have a set of data that looks similar to this:

```
[
    "L1-1_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1",
    "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-1",
    "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-2",
    "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1",
    "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-2",
    "L1-3_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-3"
];
```

I need to find a way to get a referenceable layered count of each of these strings.
e.g.
How many L1-1 selections? **3**
Of the L1-1, how many were L1.0-2 selections? **2**
Of the L1-1 => L1.0-2, how many were L1.0.0-1 selections? **1**
Of the L1-1 => L1.0-2, how many were L1.0.0-2 selections? **1**
How many L1-2 selections? **2**
... etc.

I suspect that I need to somehow create some kind of refrenceable array buckets to manage the counts, but I can't seem to get a grip on what that data-structure would look like.
How should I go about getting the results I need?
I am using Es5 and lodash libraries.

Comment: Always separated by underscore `_`?

Comment: In this case, yes... and there will never be a value containing an underscore.

Comment: Always a fixed depth?  Or could there be some, say, "L1.0.0.2.5.1.0-2"?

Comment: It won't always be a fixed depth.. some of the selections may not have any layers beneath them, others may have several layers beneath them. The initial data array may contain thousands of lines and may not be a unique value (common values should of course increment the result).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` along with the function `forEach` to make a count of every token.

**This approach generates an object as follow:**

```
{
    "L1-1": 3,
    "L1-1_L1.0-1": 1,
    "L1-3_L1.0-1": 1,
    .
    .
}
```

*The keys are the combinations and the values are the counts.*

**With that object, the access to get the count is super fast by key.**

```js
const samples = [ "L1-1_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1", "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-1", "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-2", "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1", "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-2",  "L1-3_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-3" ];

const result = samples.reduce((a, s) => {
  let previous =  "", separator = "";
  s.split("_").forEach(t => {
    previous += separator + t;
    a[previous] = (a[previous] || (a[previous] = 0)) + 1;
    separator = "_";
  });
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log("L1-1:\t\t\t",                 result['L1-1']);
console.log("L1-1_L1.0-2:\t\t",            result['L1-1_L1.0-2']);
console.log("L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-1:\t",     result['L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-1']);
console.log("L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-2:\t",     result['L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-2']);
console.log("L1-2:\t\t\t",                 result['L1-2']);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/egomezr/pen/dmLLwP.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just count the given strings who starts with the joined question string.

```js
var data = ["L1-1_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1", "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-1", "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-2", "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1", "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-2", "L1-3_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-3"],
    questions = [['L1-1'], ['L1-1', 'L1.0-2'], ['L1-1', 'L1.0-2', 'L1.0.0-1'], ['L1-1', 'L1.0-2', 'L1.0.0-2'], ['L1-2']],
    answers = questions.map(
        q => data.reduce((r, d) => r + d.startsWith(q.join('_')), 0)
    );

console.log(answers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a nested object with a key for each child level and a `count` property to indicate how many times that level occurs, e.g.

```
{
  'L1-1': {
    count: 2,
    'L1.0-1': {
      count: 1,
      ...
     },
     'L1.0-2': {
       ...
     }
    },
    ...
}
```

This can be accomplished with something like

```js
var data = [
    "L1-1_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1",
    "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-1",
    "L1-1_L1.0-2_L1.0.0-2",
    "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-1",
    "L1-2_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-2",
    "L1-3_L1.0-1_L1.0.0-3"
];

function insert(object,key) {
    if (!object[key]) {
        object[key] = {};
        object[key].count = 1;
    } else {
        object[key].count++;
    }
}

var answers = data.reduce(function(a,c) {
 var strings = c.split('_');
 strings.reduce(function(ap,cp){
  insert(ap, cp);
  return ap[cp];
 }, a)
 return a;
}, {})

console.log(answers)
```

You can then examine the `answers` object, either by hand or programmatically, to find your answers. I believe the above code should work for any depth and mixed depth.